# Windows Authentication Frequently Failing with pymssql

Tags: python, windows-authentication, pymssql

I am having a problem where Windows Authentication has almost completed stopped working for pymssql 2.1.3. It was working last week, but now when I try and use my AD login, it fails almost every time with the error `(20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (878240-SQLdb4:1433)\n')`, though it does manage to succeed about 1 in every 100 attempts. I have Sql Server Management Studios installed on the server where my Python code is running from, and Windows Authentication appears to be working fine. I checked the sql log for failed logins and I couldn't see any attempts.

Here is my code:

```
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connection(server='myserver',database='database1')
```

Any ideas to make it connect consistently?

*Edit: It appears to work more consistently if it is the first time I have tried logging in after a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just had to switch to pyodbc which has better support for Windows authentication. <s>Keep in mind that the latest release of pyodbc (4.0.21) does not support Python 3.6, so you need to use 3.5.</s> Apparently there is a wheel for python 3.6, but I haven't tested it and it appears pip is unable to natively install it on Windows. I also had to change a few things such as the connection string and how stored procedures are called (pyodbc does not have the callproc function). Here is my connection string now:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(server='server',database='database',Trusted_Connection='yes', driver = '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}')
```

Comment: *"the latest release of pyodbc (4.0.21) does not support Python 3.6, so you need to use 3.5"* - That is not true. Python 3.6 wheel files for Mac and Windows are available via pip (ref: [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyodbc/4.0.21)), and 4.0.21 will install from source under Python 3.6 on Linux.